# Form Validation through an ng-template

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have a form that contains a template outlet, used in a modal. I'd like to be able to include inputs and such in the template, and have their validation work with the form. I can't put the form inside the template, because the completion button is contained in the modal's template and it needs to know if the form is valid. The communication between my component and the modal is through attributes or through `let`s in the ng-template

I found one other question that touches on a similar issue, but the answer said something about a content container, which didn't seem to really address what I need.

The relevant portions of my modal's template

```html
<form #modalForm="ngForm">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: modalData}"></ng-container>
    <button (click)="success()" [disabled]="modalForm.invalid">
</form>
```

The relevant portions of this modal instance's code

```html
<ng-template let-data>
    <div [ngSwitch]="index">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="0">
            <input type="text" name="inp" [(ngModel)]="inpu" #inp="ngModel" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Thanks, all!

Comment: Have you tried adding a new key value pair with the form being the value inside the ngTemplateOutletContext? `{$implicit: modelData, blahblah: formRef}` Then within the ng-template add the attribute `let-_blahblah__ = "__blahblah__"`

Comment: @SheriKwong How would I invalidate the form with that though? Preferably without much or any javascript